# how fetch data from two table in codeigniter by using inner join

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new for `codeigniter` and problem in `Active Record(JOIN).`

```
SELECT emp.name
    ,emp_detail.salary
FROM emp
INNER JOIN emp_details ON emp.id=emp_details.eid
                         AND emp_detail.salary > 5000
```

How to change above query in `codeigniter`.

Comment: above query working??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had typo within your query. I have updated yours into Active Records. This'll work for you..

```
$this->db->select('e.name,ed.salary');
$this->db->from('emp e');
$this->db->join('emp_details ed','e.id = ed.eid');
$this->db->where('ed.salary > 5000');
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: (_FYI : you can accept or upvote an answer which really helps you.._)

Comment: similar query gives me only first attribute i.e. e.name in these case.. what could be the issue

Comment: Are you grouping the data with group by or may be fetching only single record

Comment: grouping the data in foreach loop to show all from db tab,e

Comment: Please post your question on SO @user2906608